# Create Ad Hoc network with Mobile Broadband Stick

Tags: network-share, ip-address, adhoc-network

I have a PLC (programmable logic controller) with an ethernet connection, temporarily i need to connect it via an ethernet cable to a laptop, i will put a Orange broadband stick into the laptop to give it internet access. What would i need to do to pass the internet through to the PLC, or do i actually need to do anything. What default gateway do i put into the PLC?

EDIT: Its a windows PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I'm familiar with the Orange sticks, but I've used Clear/Rover's wireless broadband devices and forwarded traffic for a Beagleboard, so it shouldn't be too different. You probably just need to do the following (Windows XP): right click the connection, choose Properties, and under Advanced, choose "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection". That will set up Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) and turn on DHCP on the ethernet interface.

Comment: got it, thought it would be a simple thing like that, not to belittle your answer :)